# icacls remove all groups from ACL

Tags: powershell-2.0, acl

I am trying to amend the ACL on a file using icacls. I want this file to be owned by Administrator and be accessible to Administrator only. I found out how to make administrator the owner of the files, and I know how to remove a group from the security list but I don't know how to remove all groups but the administrator group if I don't know the name of the other groups.

I am looking for a way to tell Windows that I only want to let Administrator access the file and remove any other user/group if there is any.

I tried using the wildcard character but it doesn't work.

Here's my script:

```
$domain     = [Environment]::UserDomainName
$user       = [Environment]::UserName
icacls $myinvocation.mycommand.path /setowner "$domain\$user" /T
icacls $myinvocation.mycommand.path /grant "$domain\$user"

icacls $myinvocation.mycommand.path
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, you can use `:r` after grant (see [Docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)). However, in practice I couldn't make this work. I think `:r` means "Replace permisions *only for the specified user*".

I've tested the following solution in Powershell and it works fine though.

```
# Reset the folder to just it's inherited permissions
icaclsname c:\temp\test /reset 

# Then, disable inheritance and remove all inherited permissions
icacls c:\temp\test /inheritance:r

# Note the :r after grant. It's not now needed, but I've left it in anyway.
# Permissions replace previously granted explicit permissions.
# Also note the :F, where : is escaped with `. This grants FULL CONTROL.
# You can replace F with whatever level of control is required for you.
icacls c:\temp\test /grant:r $domain\$user`:F
```

Comment: nice one RB but sadly the :r generates an error in powershell :(
I guess I'll have to use Set-Acl instead...

Comment: @Bluz Sorry - didn't see the Powershell tag. I've completely changed my answer - please try this one now (I've actually tested it this time!!)

Comment: Awesome ! That new script does the job perfectly ! Thank you very much ! :D